# dojo attachevent. I want to trigger a handler in an entirely different component

Tags: javascript, dojo

In dojo,
You can have something to this effect.

```
<div id='outer' dojoType=OuterWidget>
  <div dojoType=InnerWidget dojoAttachEvent='onmousein:_privateHandler, on...'>
  </div>
</div>
```

But my scenario, is that I want to lay out a declarative description of my application widget layout like that, but have the mousein event of the inner component trigger a handler on the outer component.

I might have to resort to onmousein='dijit.byId("outer").outerHandler()'
But it seems like dojo should have built a way to do this.

Also, on a related not (if someone knows how to do extention points) I want to be able to say that an extension point of the inner element should merely refer to some handler of the outer. (The only distinction now being that I'd like to point an extension point to the outer handler as opposed to just a native DOM event.)

I would *really* appreciate any help you guys can offer on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Dijit does have a [getParent](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/_Contained#getParent) method for widgets which implement a Container-Contained relationship, but it basically does a walk up the DOM looking for a node with the markings of a Dijit Widget (a widgetid attribute, IIRC.  Once you establish this relationship, you should be able to simply do something like a dojo.connect to bind one event to another.  You'd best avoid ids, since they're instance specific.  It's a bit like using a global variable.

Comment: Peller, Yes it is like global variables, but I'm describing my application using declarative markup. The id's *must* be unique. The whole concept behind developing components, is that they should be able to exist apart from any parent, or within any parent, as long as data is provided to them somehow. Let me know what you think of that. See my answer:

Comment: which is why you may want to avoid ids.  If you want to create a reproducible pattern in markup, you should rely on some other pattern to locate relative code.  You may be able to use some other pattern, like looking for an immediate pattern or doing a query based on class.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this worked:
Asume the html represents a template for the parent class, which always includes a child:

```
<div > // no id or dojoType specified in the parent's template:
    <div dojoType='innerWidget' idOfWidgetThatShouldHandleMouseIn=${id}>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ${id} will be mapped to the exact id of *whatever* *instance* is created of the parent component.

Comment: this ought to work and might make sense where the relationship between innerWidget and outerWidget is non-obvious.  other times you may have a relationship of innerWidget/outerWidget where the widgets should be able to find each other based on some other relationship.  That way you would not need this id, and you'd be able to use this code with copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks.. But consider that this level of declaration, is intended to wire up the program at the application level, not reusable component level. At the individual component level, I would choose to never require that a component know what context it is running in. But at the application level, this level of markup is to *instruct* components, what context they're running in. I think of it like wiring up a Mac OS X Cocoa app. On your note, if a widget needs to be able to find another widget based on relationship, I like to still have children not be aware of parents. Other way around is fine..

Comment: both patterns have their place.